# Zigbee packet analysis using Killerbee

Tags: zigbee, tinyos

I am working on Tiny OS using Micaz sensors on Zigbee platform. I am also using Killerbee to analyze the data packets. Can anyone suggest how to read those hexadecimal values?

Because the node-ID I am assigning while burning the nodes are not seen in the data packets at all.

Comment: This is a pretty niche question.  You might have more luck emailing some of the project members directly.  If you don't want to do that, we'd need some more detailed information about your setup: how are the components configured, how are they connected together, what output you are currently seeing, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tool I've found for analyzing ZigBee / 802.15.4 packets is [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). You just need to figure a way of getting the raw packets into pcap format. I've got a blog post on adapting the Microchip ZENA analyzer to output pcap format here: 
http://jdesbonnet.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-microchip-zena-zigbee802154.html